# Keep checkbox checked after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to fetch all objects from the favorites array and set the checkbox to checked
I've checked online and tried using the localStorage for that yet nothing works and the values aren't saved after refreshing.

Would appreciate any help!

Selected Book Component :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { bookService } from '../service/book.service';

export const SelectedBook = ({ selectedBook, setFavorites, favorites, removeFavorite }) => {
  const onHandleFavorite = (book, e) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
      setFavorites([...favorites, book]);
      bookService.addFavorite(book);
    } else {
      removeFavorite(book);
    }
  };

  const isFavorite = () => {
    if (!favorites.includes(selectedBook)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='selected-book-container'>
      <input type='checkbox' checked={isFavorite()} onChange={(e) => onHandleFavorite(selectedBook, e)} />
      <div className='title'>{selectedBook?.title}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Book Page component :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { bookService } from '../service/book.service.js';
import { BookList } from '../cmps/BookList';
import { SelectedBook } from '../cmps/SelectedBook.jsx';
import { utilService } from '../service/util.service';

export const BookPage = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [selectedBook, setSelectedBook] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    bookService.favoriteQuery().then((res) => {
      setFavorites(res);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    bookService.query().then((res) => {
      setBooks(res);
      setSelectedBook(res[0]);
    });
  }, []);

  document.onkeydown = checkKey;

  function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
      if (index === 0) return;
      setIndex(index - 1);
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      if (index >= books.length - 1) return;
      setIndex(index + 1);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedBook(books[index]);
  }, [index]);

  const removeFavorite = (book) => {
    setFavorites(favorites.filter((favorite) => favorite.id !== book.id));
    bookService.removeFavorite(selectedBook);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='main-container main-layout'>
        <div className='second'>
          <SelectedBook
            selectedBook={selectedBook}
            setFavorites={setFavorites}
            favorites={favorites}
            removeFavorite={removeFavorite}
          />
          <BookList books={favorites} removeFavorite={removeFavorite} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='footer-container'>
        <section className='footer'>Footer</section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Service :

```
async function favoriteQuery() {
  try {
    let favorites = await _loadeFavoriteFromStorage();
    if (!favorites) return (favorites = []);
    return favorites;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('cannot load favorites', err);
  }
}

function _loadeFavoriteFromStorage() {
  return storageService.loadFromStorage(STORAGE_FAVORITE_KEY);
}
```

Storage Service :

```
export const storageService = {
    loadFromStorage,
    saveToStorage
}

function saveToStorage(key, val) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(val))
}

function loadFromStorage(key) {
    var val = localStorage.getItem(key)
    return JSON.parse(val)
}
```

thanks for any kind of help

Comment: We're gonna need to see the `storageService` code

Comment: added the service

Comment: How are you saving the favorites? I don't see any code calling `saveToStorage`. Could you try creating a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with something like codesandbox. You can use the one I've used to check that your storageService is working as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-platform-xklxy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating localstorage each time that checked is being changed. You're calling setFavorites with a new set of favorites but this is just changing state. I would suggest creating a function within the book page component which does

```
function changeFavorite(book, checked){
saveToStorage(book?, checked)
rerender()
}
```

and having rerender set the state of favorites to whatever is in localstorage to ensure that you have a single source of truth which is found in localstorage and that you change that and not anything else

I'll just add

```
    if (!favorites.includes(selectedBook)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
```

Could really look like

```
const isFavorite () => favorites.includes(selectedBook)
```

I also didn't quite understand how you're doing about storing the books in object storage. You should probably have an id of some sorts which you use to save favorite information with